# how to update a table row value using a row value from another table in Apex Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

[image]I have a bulk stock table with a quantity variable. I also have a quantity variable for a table called purchase order. When a user makes a purchase order I want the quantity they have inserted in the purchase order table to be deleted in the Bulk stock table. I am doing this using an SQL oracle software called Apex. I am struggling with SQL syntax i believe:

```
Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

this is my code

```
UPDATE Bulk_stock
   SET Bulk_stock.bulk_quantity = Bulk_stock.bulk_quantity - purchase_order.order_quantity,

 WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM purchase_order
        WHERE Bulk_stock.stock_id = purchase_order.stock_id);
```

Comment: Could you pass in the value of the current purchase order id into the query as a bind variable? How does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: The insert is done automatically using that oracle apex form. This is the code i want to put as a process on the page AFTER the insert is done according to the image above. there is no extra code

Comment: Are you allowed to create a `TRIGGER` in the database for encapsulating this business logic?

Comment: yes I am allowed. I tried creating a trigger but apex always cries about syntax. If you could help with a Begin-End; correct syntax for this kind of update.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: This one worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631582/how-to-trigger-an-update-on-a-table-row-value-using-a-row-value-from-another-tab/40632289#40632289

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra comma after `purchase_order.order_quantity`. Besides in your update statement you refer to `purchase_order.order_quantity` which is not correct since the update is happening on `Bulk_stock` table.

Can you try this one:

```
UPDATE Bulk_stock
   SET Bulk_stock.bulk_quantity = Bulk_stock.bulk_quantity - nvl( SELECT purchase_order.order_quantity
         FROM purchase_order
        WHERE purchase_order.stock_id = Bulk_stock.stock_id WHERE ROWNUM=1), 0) WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
     FROM purchase_order
    WHERE Bulk_stock.stock_id = purchase_order.stock_id);
```

Comment: This would always update all rows in `Bulk_stock`, right?

Comment: Yes. But after update, the result will be that the bulk_quantity will remain unchanged if no value else will change to the value to reflect quantity that is ordered.

Comment: Yea, my point was that this could be an expensive operation if the table has millions of rows.

Comment: Modified the query to prevent update if no orders exist for the item in stock.

Comment: This still might not be what the OP is after, because it would keep reducing the quantity of orders that had already been processed earlier, during each update.

Comment: Isn't `SET Bulk_stock.bulk_quantity = Bulk_stock.bulk_quantity - purchase_order.order_quantity` doing what I was doing? There was no order processing information in the query @kuhle specified.